# Google ANR Crash Report, Can you Contact The User?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-play

Is there a way to message a user who sent in a crash report - to ask them about what was happening right before?

Also this is my stack trace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity
>   {com.alexgierczyk.starific/com.alexgierczyk.starific.RunnerActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'com.alexgierczyk.starific.DemoRenderer
>   com.alexgierczyk.starific.DemoGLSurfaceView.mRenderer' on a null
>   object reference  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4507)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4560)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:197)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6891)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>   Caused by: **java.lang.NullPointerException**: Attempt to read from field
>   'com.alexgierczyk.starific.DemoRenderer
>   com.alexgierczyk.starific.DemoGLSurfaceView.mRenderer' on a null
>   object reference  at
>   com.alexgierczyk.starific.RunnerActivity.onStop(RunnerActivity.java:851)
>     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1291)
>     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6752)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4504)
>     ... 10 more

It says ... 10 more, is there a way to see those other 10?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not initiate a discussion with the user from google play console as it does not give you enough data to do so. In case your user left you a message with the error report, you can read it in the User Message tab.

In case you want to initiate communication with your user, you can probably try some in-app feedback tool that has crash reporting enabled so that you get some more information about the crash, and also can initiate a communication with the user if needed.

I used a sdk called instabug that gave me steps performed by the user to get a crash. But there are other tools in the market as well which might help in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.  I take it there's not a way to see the "...10 more" part?

Comment: No there is not. That is part of your stacktrace and google play captured only till there.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to message a user who sent in a crash report - to ask
>   them about what was happening right before?

No not possible, because with crash reports Google is not providing any user related information which is required to contact like email,phone number,...